# python xml writer

Tags: python, xml, ironpython

i tried to do this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.Element('xml')
projects = ["a", "e", "u"]
for i in projects:
    project = ET.SubElement(root,'project')
    project.set('name', i)
    designs = ["a", "e", "u"]
    for u in designs:
        design = ET.SubElement(project,'design')
        design.set('name', u)
        vars = ["a", "e", "u"]
        for z in vars:
            param = ET.SubElement(design,'param')
            param.set('name', z)
            value = ET.SubElement(param,'value')
            value.text = "var"
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
tree.write('projects.xml')
```

if I execute it with ipy.exe it works exactly as it should, but I need to execute it from the scripting Interface of another program. The scripting interface uses IronPython 2.6.10920.0 on .NET 2.0.50727.5466
It runs without error but the file it creates is always empty. If I try to delete said file it says that it's still opened in the program. Is there a command to release the xml file or am I overlooking something?

UPDATE: If I close the program in question after running the script, the xml file is created normally

UPDATE: A simple filewriter like this works perfectly

```
f = open("pythontest.txt", "w")
projects = ["a", "e", "u"]
for i in projects:
    f.write("Name: " + i)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is also possible to pass a file object to an ElementTree constructor. Perhaps, try creating the file with that and then closing the file at the end?

Comment: that did the trick, I don't know why but I'm happy that it works. Thank you very much!